# Switching views for iphone application - is this the right way?

Tags: iphone, ios4

After looking for many hours to find a working view switching code, I finally found [a great tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ph3XhJD8QAI) on YouTube. It was exactly what I needed as I needed to switch views when buttons are pressed.

I just wonder if the techniques used in that video are valid. The used code to switch screens is

```
viewsViewController *second = [[viewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
```

Where viewsViewController (or any class that is used there) is a class that's a subclass of UIViewController. This class is made by clicking File > New File > Add UIViewController subclass.

Is this method according to the Apple guidelines? Is this method memory friendly?

I sure hope the technique is valid. All other examples contained too little information so I couldn't make the example to work. And this is very stylish and short code which works .

Answer (score 0):

That's one way to do it. When you present a view controller modally, there's some expectation that the view controller will go away at some point and the user will return to the parent view controller.

Another option is to employ a UINavigationController, to which you can send `-pushViewController:animated:` messages.

Yet another way is to let a UITabBarController switch view controllers for you when the user hits the corresponding tab.

One more: you can set the window's `rootViewController` property, at which point the window will add the view controller's view as a subview of itself.

Your best bet is to read through the [*View Controller Programming Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1).

Comment: When you mention "expectation"  in your first paragraph. Do you mean expectation of the user or of the program?

If possible I don't want to show a navigation bar at the top or bottom. Can I avoid that and still use the controller? I'll see if I can figure that out. Thanks @caleb!

Comment: @Rick: Both. You usually present a view controller modally in response to some temporary situation: a request for information from the user, informational interlude, changing settings, etc. After calling `-presentModalViewController:animated:`, you're expected to eventually call `-dismissModalViewController:animated:`. Read more [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html). And yes, you can definitely use a navigation controller without showing the navigation bar at the top.

Comment: I doubt the navigationcontroller is smart. I don't have a clear hierarchy. People can go from screen 1 to 5, to 3 to 10, back to 5 and to 1 and to 11.

Writing this seem to work, but I doubt it's valid:
      secondview *second = [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:false];
        [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

I'd would like to stick to this situation if possible, because it suits my needs for total navigation freedom. I'm only doubting about the memory management.

Comment: Or can I perform an onload action on the new view in which I dismiss the previous view controller?

I'm brainstorming... But what if I define all my viewcontrollers in the AppDelegate.h and I can dismiss the previous view from any other view. Or is that dirty programming? Not sure how I can find out what the previous view was though.

Comment: I realy have to get used to these apple keyboard shortcuts. Posting too many replies now, lol...

About the onload dismissal. I don't get an error doing [super dismissmodelviewcontroller:true]; in the viewdidload of the next screen...

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it. Be aware of some issues. Both views will be in memory, which is okay if they are a reasonable size. The modal view animates above the parent.

There are other models that you can use for simple navigation, if that's your main goal. I would suggest looking at UINavigationController and see if that might better meet your needs. It is probably the most common method to navigate views and provided a lot of the foundation of view management saving you that effort.

Comment: My application will have over 20 different views. It isn't really user friendly and beautiful to use navigation at the top and/or bottom. Allthough there will be a menu at the bottom which can brings the user back to one of the four main screens. The rest is navigated through buttons in each view. 

If there are all stored in memory and not released when the user goes to another screen this doesn't seem to be a good option. Can't I release all screens? Or release them all except the root? I can define a root screen if necessary.